# JQX Grid server data response example

Tags: jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I'm trying to implement a jqxGrid, using sorting and paging on the server. I don't have access to the server itself. Taking an example from:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/phpintegration/php-server-side-grid-paging-and-sorting.htm

I implement the client-side and want to use a mock static file as a response. I can't manage to figure out what kind of JSON response format is meant to be returned.

1. How do I 'catch' and edit/format the JSON response from the server? (Where in the code?)
2. Is there anywhere a working example of a jqgrid with sorting done on the server, to be viewable online? (So I can observe the data structure returned).

Answer (score 0):

1. What do you mean exactly? Do you want to edit the data itself or the view of the data? If it is the later one you can use cellsrendered. For a live demo look [here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?(arctic)#demos/jqxgrid/gridcellclass.htm). You can also change the value here since you have access to the value field but it is by column.
2. Yes, look [here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/php/index.htm#demos/php/serversorting.htm).

Answer (score -2):

1. http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/
   You can find there information about the datasource.
2. http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/
   You can find there (right menu):

   PHP Integration
   ASP.NET Integration

   You can find there what ever yo need (sorting filtering and so)